# How to escape parentheses in jsp

Tags: jsp, escaping, parentheses

I keep getting errors on this line of code:

`pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(
                    "SELECT * FROM products WHERE category IN" +

                    "(" + "SELECT catid FROM category WHERE name= currentcat " + ")"
           );`

I'm guessing the problem is my parentheses. If it's not then what's wrong with my code?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with parentheses. A varchar value must be surrounded by single quotes in SQL:

```
SELECT catid FROM category WHERE name = 'currentcat'
```

The error message, which you didn't post, usually contains meaningful information. Always read (and post) the complete and exact error message.